# I'm currently experiencing an error with GDB debugging on Eclipse MacOS Big Sur

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, debugging, gdb

I'm currently having a strange error after installing my GDB through Homebrew on Big Sur. I have configured everything to my Eclipse properly (with my GDB linked as the debugger). However every time I attempt to start a debug, nothing happens, and the following appears in the console:

**00:01:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project generic_project ****

make all

make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

00:01:58 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 112ms)**

Is there anyway to get around this? I truly cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The output suggests a valid build step that succeeds. Are you sure that you're actually **debugging** your project, rather than just **building** the debug configuration?

Comment: @nanofarad I have set up the GDB and GDB file in my configurations, and then I attempt to debug as a Local C/C++ Project, and it gives me what I present above.

Comment: Does Eclipse switch to the debug perspective? If not, did you do it? (IIRC there is an option to switch automatically.)

Comment: I have it configured to switch to the debug perspective, however it just tries to build the debug, which is already built, as opposed to actually commencing a debug

Answer (score 1):

I am on Sierra but experienced the exact same symptoms and resolved the issues by downgrading gdb versions to 9.2.2.

It turns out that the latest versions of Eclipse CDT and the newer `brew install gdb@10.2` do not play nicely. Sadly no earlier brew formulas are currently maintained either.

Your options are to git clone/re-build an older version, or to download the old 9.2.2 raw gitlab ruby script and install it as a brew formula locally.  And then follow the code signing steps you have probably seen referenced elsewhere.

Something like:

```sh
% curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/95b9a2a56a8917eba5491805e3886b05573fab71/Formula/gdb.rb > ./gdb.rb
% brew uninstall gdb
% brew install ./gdb.rb
% # Assume you've created gdb-entitlements.xml and a private cert per many gdb signing instructions found elsewhere
% codesign --entitlements gdb-entitlement.xml -fs your-code-signing-cert-name $(which gdb)
```

After a recommended reboot, and a modification to debug configurations (eclipse wide and/or project-wide settings) to reference the symbolic link /usr/local/bin/gdb you should be good.

The whole process is pretty well explained [here](https://www.thomasvitale.com/how-to-setup-gdb-and-eclipse-to-debug-c-files-on-macos-sierra/) although the downgrade is to gdb 8.3.

The Eclipse forum [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?SQ=0&t=search&srch=gdb&btn_submit=Search) did tip me off to this version incompatibility but I can't for the life of me find the link that was instrumental.