# Eclipse Debugging C++ doesn't work on MacOS

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I installed Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers on my Mac. However, when I click on the debug icon on the menu, the Debug Perspective Window doesn't pop out at all. No step into/over icon debugging choices show up either.

Specifically, after I click Run -> Debug as -> C++/C Application, it shows the following info and the Launching Debug is 96%, then stucks forever. No debug window jumps out.

```
***Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project generic_project ****
make all
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 158ms)
```

[image]

I config GDB (version=9.2) according to [this tutorial](https://www.thomasvitale.com/how-to-setup-gdb-and-eclipse-to-debug-c-files-on-macos-sierra/). I didn't use brew install because it will install 10.2 GDB which is not compatible with Eclipse from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867339/im-currently-experiencing-an-error-with-gdb-debugging-on-eclipse-macos-big-sur/). I guess it's the problem of my GDB but I successfully completed all steps in that tutorial. Please give me any suggestions on how to make C++ debugger works on Eclipse. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right off the bat, the guide you used recommends gdb 8.3.

Comment: @sweenish that tutorial was written on 2017. I don't know if GDB 8.3 still works for now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867339/im-currently-experiencing-an-error-with-gdb-debugging-on-eclipse-macos-big-sur/ the answer for this question says he use gdb 9.2 on March, 2021 and there is no issue. So why not try 9.2 first?

Comment: I can't remember the timings go these things, but gdb hasn't worked properly for a few years now. And you can't claim to have followed the guide  when you deviated at the very beginning. I don't know why you don't just use lldb. And why would gdb 8.3 not work?

Comment: @sweenish Thanks for your advice. I didn't find detailed tutorials on how to install lldb and use it on Eclipse. But I can give it a try, if gdb 8.3 doesn't work. Since I didn't use home-brew to install it, `brew uninstall` won't work for uninstallation :( Is there anyway to uninstall my current gdb completely? thanks!